# Construtor - Orientação a objeto C#

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, método, construtor

No código abaixo, é correto dizer que o construtor seria o seguinte trecho:

```
public Inicio(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```

---

Segue o código:

```
public class Inicio
{
    private Container container = new SimpleInjector.Container();

    public Inicio(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get;}

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
      
        // Sets up the basic configuration that for integrating Simple Injector with
        // ASP.NET Core by setting the DefaultScopedLifestyle, and setting up auto
        // cross wiring.
        services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
        {
            // AddAspNetCore() wraps web requests in a Simple Injector scope and
            // allows request-scoped framework services to be resolved.
            options.AddAspNetCore()

                // Ensure activation of a specific framework type to be created by
                // Simple Injector instead of the built-in configuration system.
                // All calls are optional. You can enable what you need. For instance,
                // ViewComponents, PageModels, and TagHelpers are not needed when you
                // build a Web API.
                .AddControllerActivation();
            //.AddViewComponentActivation()
            //.AddPageModelActivation()
            //.AddTagHelperActivation();

            // Optionally, allow application components to depend on the non-generic
            // ILogger (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging) or IStringLocalizer
            // (Microsoft.Extensions.Localization) abstractions.
            //options.AddLogging();
            //options.AddLocalization();
        });

        InitializeContainer();
    }

    private void InitializeContainer()
    {
        // Add application services. For instance:
        BootStrapper.Register(container);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // UseSimpleInjector() finalizes the integration process.
        app.UseSimpleInjector(container);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        // Always verify the container
        container.Verify();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Veja [Guia de programação C#- Constructores](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101